# Why the random number is always 0?

Tags: java

This is a simple number guessing game.Where the user has to enter a number of their choice. I tried entering 0 for 2 to 3 times and it got right.But it always gets 0 as the random number. What can be the solution for this problem ?

```
class Main {

    static int random;
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int guessResult = 1;
        int randomGuess = 0;

        while (guessResult != -1) {
            System.out.println("Guess a number between 0 and 50 : ");

            randomGuess = userInput.nextInt();

            guessResult = checkGuess(randomGuess);
        }

        System.out.println("Yes the random number is " + randomGuess);
    }

    public static int getRandomNum() {
        random = (int) (Math.random() * 50);
        return random;

    }

    public static int checkGuess(int g) {
        if (g == random) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return g;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any usage of `getRandomNum()`

Comment: Thanks I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `getRandomNum` method. The value you're trying to print (`randomGuess`) is a value from `System.in`.

Answer (score 0):

At

```
static int random;
```

your random number isn't set.

So you need call

```
Random rn = new Random();
random = rn.nextInt(51);
```

(random nextInt calls are exclusive, so you have to count on more)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Number_game 
{ 
static int random;
static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int guessResult = 1;
    int randomGuess = 0;

        System.out.println("Guess a number between 0 and 50 : ");
        randomGuess = userInput.nextInt();
        guessResult = checkGuess(randomGuess);
        System.out.println("The random number is "+guessResult );
}

public  static int checkGuess(int g)
{
    random = (int)(Math.random()*50);
    if(g==random)
    {
    return g;
    }
    else
    {
    return random;
    }
}  

}



Try This code
```